# What does it mean when the exponent is beneath the base number?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, theta-functions

I am familiar with the exponential function and the power function.

**Exponential Function**: $y=3^x$

**Power of Function**: $y=x^3$

But what do the numbers under the theta in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF5GZ.png) represent?

$h_(x)=_0 + _1 x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the context, but in this case it is probably just $\theta = (\theta_0,\theta_1)$, a vector with two entries. In general, subscripts are usually indices, e.g. $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for sequences.

Comment: Thank you... I am new to mathematical machine learning... just a quick question am I correct to assume that θ is basically a sum of (θ0,θ1)

Comment: Not really a sum, more of a list with (in this case) two entries.